# How to get Lambda Error in Mail using CW Alarm and SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get the error in the lambda through mail, but I need to include the CW alarm in between to ensure that we have ability of enable/disable the alarm. How can I achieve this?

current method I am using is lambda(that gives out error)->CW alarm->SNS->lambda->netcool API, but I am not able to get the error in the mail

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

1. **Handle Exceptions** using `try catch` or `try except` (depends on the language)
2. If any exception is found, **publish an SNS message on certain topic from within the lamba** with the error message on.

This is even cost effective because it cuts out the cloudwatch alarm.

Make sure to add permission to the lambda IAM such like -

```
{
    "Action" : [
        "sns:Publish",
        "sns:Subscribe"
    ],
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Resource" : [
        { "Ref" : "desired SNS topic ARN" }
    ]
}
```

[This might help](https://www.learnaws.org/2021/05/05/aws-sns-boto3-guide/) you out.

Also, in sns you can just give your email address (as subscriber) and get messages right away.

Best wishes.